# Move half files in directory in bash

Tags: bash, file

I'm trying to mv several files from a directory:

```
/images
01.png
02.png
03.png
...
```

I want to mv half of the in another directory:

```
for file in *.png
do
  mv ?
done
```

so i have :

```
/imagesProcessed
01.png
03.png
....
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So every odd number? Or every other file if sorted alphabetically? Or random?

Comment: every file. They are sorted but we cannot use the name of the file as they can change

Comment: But **which** files? Which do you want to move?

Comment: the .png files in the directory

Comment: Ok, then. What do you mean by *half*?

Comment: 1 out of two (sorry my english is a little limited) but as the example if i have
1.png
2.png
3.png
4.png
5.png
i want to obtain

1.png
3.png
5.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106893/discussion-between-user3895503-and-pacholik).

Comment: `mv *[13579].png imagesProcessed`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Every odd number:

```
mv {01..99..2}.png imagesProcessed
```

where last file is `99.png` (or lower - then you'll see some errors but will work).

### Every other file if sorted alphabetically:

```
IFS='
'
mv `ls *.png | sed -n 1~2p` imagesProcessed
```

### Random files:

```
IFS='
'
mv `ls *.png | sort -R | sed -n 1~2p` imagesProcessed
```

---

edit: change internal field separator so it works when you have spaces in names

Answer (score 3):

If there aren't too many files:

```
files=(*.png)
half_num_files=$((${#files[@]} / 2))
mv "${files[@]:0:half_num_files}" imagesProcessed
```

What does this do?

- `files=( *.png )` stores all matching filenames in an array named `files`.
- `${#files[@]}` is the length of this array, the number of files. So `$((${#files[@]} / 2))` uses arithmetic substitution to get half of that.
- `${arr[@]:a:b}` expands to subarray starting at index `a`, for a length `b`. So, `${arr[@]:0:half_num_files}` is the first half of the array.

Comment: what happens if you pass large number of files?

Comment: @SmS depending on how large "large" is, either bash will run out of memory or mv will get an argument limit exceeded error.